# In Angular how can I pass the response of my post request as one of the parameters to go into another post request?

Tags: angular, redux, action, ngrx, ngxs

I have a form with two sections, that dispatch two post request actions, the second request needs parameters from the first one to be successfully sent. But I'm not sure how :( I have the request and response of the first action working fine but I'm just not sure how or where to implement the logic - should it be in the service? a reducer? I tried forkjoin then realised I had no idea what I was doing. Thanks in advance for any help!

My component :

```
    const newArtist = this.store.dispatch(new CreateArtist({
      ...generalDetails,
      hometown,
    }))

    const newArtistExtraInfo = this.store.dispatch(new CreateDiscography({
      ...songCatalogue
    }
    ));

    forkJoin([newArtist, newArtistExtraInfo]).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`the results are in : ${result}`)
    })
```

Comment: Which parameters of the first request do you need to use in the second request?

Comment: the first request gives a response of a token and and id and they would both need to be sent as parameters for the CreateDiscography action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the results of the first action dispatched then you most likely want to read the updated state after `CreateArtist` has been handled.

In your component you could use a `Selector` that returns the most recent create artist which resulted from the handling of `CreateArtist` by the `ArtistState`:

`@Select(ArtistState.latestArtist) artist$: Observable<Artist>;`

```
this.store.dispatch(new CreateArtist(..))
.pipe(
   withLatestFrom(this.artist$)
)
.subscribe(([_, artistInfo]) => {
  this.store.dispatch(new CreateDiscography({ .., artistInfo.token, artistInfo.id });
})
```

So here you dispatch the create artist action, then read the state after creation to grab the artist specific information you need to dispatch the follow up discography action.

Another option would be that your state dispatches as `ArtistCreated` action containing the token/id you are after, and you component subscribes to that via the action stream where it can then dispatch the discography action.

Comment: thank you for your response, its really appreciated - can you just clarify the use of the _, before the returned artist info object. I'm still learning but wanted to know why you need to place it into brackets with the preceding _, . Many thanks!

Comment: ok so i've just read up and as withLatestFrom takes two sources and the most recent snapshots from both - but as there isn't anything besides the createArtist action, i guess the _, is a placeholder?

Comment: The _ is just an alias for what is returned from the first dispatch Observable.  
The other answers here are correct for RxJs but for NGXS specifically you should not rely on the `store.dispatch` Observable returning anything - it currently returns the whole state but soon it will be change to `void` in the upcoming [v4 release](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/827)

Comment: ahhh ok cool, thanks for the heads up - i'll keep that in mind moving forwards. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could pipe in the second request with the RxJS [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator. Try the following

```js
firstRequest().pipe(
  switchMap(responseFirst => secondRequest(responseFirst)),
  catchError(errorFirst => of(errorFirst))
).subscribe(
  responseSecond => { },
  errorSecond => { }
);
```

Now the first request will be completed and it's response will be used as the argument for the second request. There are other higher order mapping operators like `mergeMap`, `concatMap` and `exhaustMap` that are used for specific purposes.

Comment: brilliant - i'm going to give it a  go now, thank you for helping - really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

for that you need to extend the effect that handles `CreateArtist` to dispatch an another action.

```js
ofType(actions.CreateArtist),
switchMap(action => this.http.get('url1')),
// this action goes to effects again to its own handler.
map(response => new CreateDiscography(someParams)),
```